# Send data from Activity to Service

Tags: android, android-service

How can I send data from the current `Activity` to a background `Service` class which is running at certain time? I tried to set into `Intent.putExtras()` but I am not getting it in `Service` class

Code in `Activity` class which calls the `Service`.

```
Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, SchedulerEventService.class);
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("test", "Daily");
        startService(mServiceIntent);
```

Code in `Service` class. I treid to put in `onBind()` and `onStartCommand()`. None of these methods prints the value.

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //String data = intent.getDataString();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Starting..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.d(APP_TAG,intent.getExtras().getString("test"));


    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be `onStartCommand`. If you never call `bindService` on your activity `onBind` will not be called, and use `getStringExtra()` instead of `getExtras()`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Starting..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(APP_TAG,intent.getStringExtra("test"));
    return START_STICKY; // or whatever your flag
}
```

Comment: I am getting nullPointer when i try to access in onStartCommand()

Comment: put if (intent != null) in the onStartCommand. But when you call startService onStartCommand will be called with your intent. Post your logcat for this nullPointerException.

Comment: Of course with your original code you will get nullPointerException on the line intent.getExtras().getStringt() since intent.getExtras is null.

Comment: Continue with the same question. Does anybody know how to create new Pending Intent evertime for Service instead of updating existing one?

Comment: What do you mean by the above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass primitive data types that can be put into Intent I would recommend to use IntentService. To start the IntentService, type in your activity:

```
startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class).putExtra("test", "Hello work");
```

Then create a service class that extends IntentService class:

```
public class YourService extends IntentService {

String stringPassedToThisService;

public YourService() {
    super("Test the service");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    stringPassedToThisService = intent.getStringExtra("test");

    if (stringPassedToThisService != null) {
        Log.d("String passed from activity", stringPassedToThisService);
    // DO SOMETHING WITH THE STRING PASSED
    }
}
```