# Android: How to pass data from Activity to Service?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

My aplication is making notification in any specific time. I'm using BroadcastReceiver and Service class where the notificationManager is.
I need to pass some data(title of item) to notification.
What is the best way?

This is in main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_day);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(Config.context, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Config.context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Config.context.getSystemService(Config.context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Here is my BrodacastReceiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String title = intent.getStringExtra(DayActivity.EXTRA_TITLE);
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1);

    }    
}
```

And here Service class

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
        {
            super.onStart(intent, startId);

            mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),DayActivity.class);

            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_logo, "Title", System.currentTimeMillis());
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "Title", "Message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

            mManager.notify(0, notification);
        }
```

I tried to use intents extra but it doesnt work when the app is down.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234181/send-data-from-activity-to-service

Answer (score 1):

while starting service just put a bundle to that service intent

In Receiver:

```
    String title = intent.getStringExtra(DayActivity.EXTRA_TITLE);
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
    Bundle dataBundle=new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("key","value");
    context.startService(service1);
```

In Service:

```
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Bundle dataBundle=intent.getExtras();
        String value=dataBundle.getString("key");
    }
```

Comment: I need to pas those data from Activity. I there any difference between Bundle and direct Extra in this case?